# Empty control root object in FormBuilder

Tags: angular, angular5

I have the following form:

```
return this.fb.group({

      'day':['', [Validators.required, Validation.ruleLeaveValidator]],
      'month': ['', []],
      'year': ['', [Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.min(1920)
    });
```

And custom rule validations **ruleLeaveValidator**:

```
static ruleLeaveValidator(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    console.log(root.controls);
}
```

Whhy there is no object `root.controls`?

Comment: What exactly is `Validation` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `control` here:

```
static ruleLeaveValidator(control: FormControl) {
    console.log(control.value);

        if (control.value != null) {
            const matches = 'your_date_validation;
            return matches ? null : { 'invaliddate': true };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't know about the way you are using, but you can do custom validation like it also:

```
private ruleLeaveValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<{ [key: string]: any }> => {
        if(checkIsInvalid)
        {
            return { 'errorName': true };
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

And use like it:

```
return this.fb.group({
  'day':['', [Validators.required], this.ruleLeaveValidator()],
  'month': ['', []],
  'year': ['', [Validators.maxLength(4), Validators.min(1920)
});
```

Comment: There is no: `ValidationFn`

Comment: Why would you place the validator as a class method?